Largest prime number erroneously erased when finding all primes less than 1000
Chicharron is a lover of mathematics and once wanted to find all primes less than 1000. He did by the following steps below:
He wrote all the numbers from 2 to 1000.
He circled the number 2 and erased other multiples of 2.
Then he circled the smallest number that was not erased and erased all other multiples of that number.
He repeated it until all the numbers were either circled or erased.
While erasing the multiples of 2, he had erased two more odd primes by mistake. He did the rest of the job without any errors. Surprisingly, the number of circled numbers was exactly the amount of primes from 2 to 1000 inclusive, which he had intended to find. He asks Miguel, "What was the largest possible prime number I erased"?
Question from Technothlon 2024

Just as a side comment, the method described is the classic manual 'Sieve of Erastothenes'.

As far as I can tell it is not possible to determine because there is no unique answer to the largest erased prime. There are several possibilities that work. Is there something missing from the description of the problem?

did he start "all the other multiples of that number" at 2 each time, even though all the multiples of 2 had been marked already? Often hand-algorithms don't. I ask because, if you should have marked all multiples of n but didn't, when you get to n-squared, will you mark 2 n-squared, 3 n-squared, ... n n-squared, ... (thus knocking off n-cubed) or just pick up from  n-squared times n-squared, n-squared times (n-squared + 1), ... ?

Welcome to PE. You use terminology like circle, cross out, erase, number of, escape. I think I understand what they are in the puzzle. But may I suggest improvements for clarity (1) use amount of instead of number of to not confuse with the numbers themselves (2) in your answer you write 'you cross out a prime number', I guess that must be 'you erase a prime number' (3) I assume 'striked out' is 'crossed out'. Finally you write 'odd primes' but all primes are odd. Sorry if I misunderstood and suggested wrong  improvements.

@FirstNameLastName You make a number of points. One of them is to suggest replacing the words "number of" --- but there is nothing wrong with the OP's use of "number of". And you suggest replacing "cross out" with "erase". It's up to the OP, but both "cross out" and "erase" are OK in the context. Finally, one prime is not odd.

@RosieF : I agree ... I was confused by terminology.

Consider, as suggested by @JaapScherphuis, to ask any question about the erased pair having a unique solution, for example: "What was the smallest prime number I can not have erased?". For sure there are much more interesting questions to ask :-).

I got the answer after some thinking. When you erase a prime number, the square of the prime number escapes from being erased. For example, if you erase 3, 9 will escape. But when we erase two prime numbers, the square of the two numbers as well as the product of the numbers escape from being erased. For example, if you erase 3 and 5, then 9, 25 and 15 will escape. So now we know this, we need to find largest prime number erased.
So, when we erase 2 prime numbers, we want another two numbers to escape. If the square of the number escapes, then we can go up to maximum 31.[31^2 = 961]. But if we see as the product of numbers escaping, then we can go up to 331. So 3 and 331 will be the optimal case.
3 and 331 are erased, 9 and 993 escape. 331 squared is not within 1000, so it doesn't matter. So the answer is 331

Chicharron could have erased 3 and 37, and then the largest prime he erased is 37. Or he could have erased 23 and 43. There is no way for Miguel to know what the value is of the largest of Chicharron's two erased primes. If the problem is what is the largest value that Chicharron's largest erased prime could be, then the problem should have been phrased differently.

apart from ambiguity pointed out by @JaapScherphuis in that multiple pairs could have been erased fulfilling all further requirements, 331 is not the largest largest possible prime erased, and, also, even the largest one has multiple pairs, but that's not a ambiguous.

@FirstNameLastName I don't agree. I think $331$ is the largest possible erased prime, and it can only have been paired with $3$ as the other erased prime. The smallest erased prime $p$ can be anything from $3$ to $23$, and the second erased prime is then any prime from $37$ to at most $1000/p$.

@JaapScherphuis : I agree (I had a bug in my program) :-(

@JaapScherphuis : $37$ seems indeed a tiebreak number in the computable sequence of solution erased prime pairs in that it is the first prime who's square exceeds the, in this case, threshold $1000$.

I don't think this answer works - if you skip a prime all powers of that prime would escape, not just the square.  So skipping 3 means that 9, 27, 81, etc all escape.

@sadwak  No, because 9 will be circled and all multiples of 9 will be erased.

It's quite amazing that mistakenly erasing 2 prime numbers will only induce a finite number of errors.


 The only way that the number of circled numbers can equal the number of primes is if two non-primes mistakenly fail to be erased, in order to cancel out the two primes that were mistakenly erased.
 This can happen because if $a$ and $b$ are erased, then $a^2$, $ab$, $b^2$ and all similar products of $a$ and $b$ will not be found by the Sieve.
 For this question, the "best" case occurs when $a^2$ and $a^3$ are the two primes that get erased (while $a^4 > 1000$) because this means all multiples of $b$ are $> 1000$ so $b$ can be as big as we wish.
 Fortunately, this property holds for $7$, so we let $a=7$, and $b$ is the largest prime on the list, $997$. (The two composite numbers he failed to erase are $49$ and $343$).

 The answer is $997$.


I'm a bit confused about what the real question is trying to ask. So I considered two different questions separately.
Question 1. When Chicharron was erasing the multiples of 2, he had erased 2 more primes by mistake. So what was the possible largest prime number he had erased by mistake?

 The possible largest prime number he had erased is $89$. 
 He erased $11$ and $89$, then the non-prime number $11^2=121$ and $11\times 89=979$ are kept.

Question 2. When Chicharron was erasing the multiples of 2, he had erased 2 more primes by mistake. Then Chicharron wondering if when he is erasing the multiples of another prime number $x$, the similar mistake happens (erased another two numbers that are not multiples of $x$). And after the process finished, the amount of numbers was exactly the amount of primes from $2$ to $1000$ inclusive. Then what is the possible largest prime $x$ could be?

 The possible largest prime $x$ is $23$. 
 When Chicharron is erasing multiples of $23$, he erased $29$ and another non-prime number (for example, $29\times 31 = 899$, or  $31^2 = 961$) by mistake, then after the process finished, the amount of numbers is still $168$.

